# I want to create variables in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Tengo una imagen con su src, y quiero una variable para añadir detrás de una cadena porque necesito usarla varias veces, y más adelante podría necesitar cambiarla.

Independientemente de si es en JavaScript o en otro lugar, necesito poder colocar una variable allí. ¿Hay alguna solución para esto?

ej:
 `<img src= **variable_str** + "/IMAGES/cancha.jpg" class="card-img-top">`

quiero que en donde dice "variable_str" este mi variable y que en el src lo lea todo con la variable mas lo que esta en sting

Comment: Hello, this question should be closed because of the low quality of it, also remember that you are in a community site in Spanish and the language alone is already causing report. In response, in html it is not possible to create a variable, for that you have languages like Js, Ts, etc; that allow you to develop a structure in which you use variables.

Please check the how to ask.

Comment: Con HTML, CSS y Javascript creo que no. Con react sí, por ejemplo: <img src={variable + "/IMAGES/cancha.jpg"}>`. Y si lo que quieres es que la ruta de los archivos se adapte, creo que hay otras soluciones.